# Eliminate specific rows from an R list

Tags: r, csv, import

The following R code generates a list containing the contents of 50 csv files read from a single directory. Each of the csv files has a different number of rows.

```
fs <- list.files(my_dir, pattern=".csv$",full.names=TRUE)
l <- lapply(fs, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

When I view the list, there are some lines I need to get rid of so that I can convert the list to a single dataframe. There are three kinds of "problem" lines:

1. Lines starting with `[[I]]` in the first position, where `I` is an integer `1:50`, corresponding to the sequence of the imported csv files, 501.csv, 502.csv, etc.
2. Lines containing column names. I tried using row.names=FALSE in my list.files function, but it generated the following error: `Error in list.files(my_dir, pattern = ".csv$", full.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)`. I also tried adding skip=1 to my lapply function. It removed the column names, but created a different problem: an X appended to the front of the first and last fields in the row that contains the first observation associated with each csv file.
3. Lines that appear blank, at least to the naked eye when viewed in RStudio console. I can't tell whether these apparently empty lines will cause a problem when I try to convert the list to a dataframe.

Below is the output of str(l) and dput(sapply(l, head, 1)). I ran this in a test environment using just two partial files.

```
> str(l)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   100 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date: chr [1:100] "12/31/95" "1/1/96" "1/2/96" "1/3/96" ...
  ..$ sub1: num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ sub2: num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ tech: int [1:100] 503 503 503 503 503 503 503 503 503 503 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   66 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Date: chr [1:66] "7/4/98" "7/5/98" "7/6/98" "7/7/98" ...
  ..$ sub1: num [1:66] NA NA 1.62 NA NA 1.32 NA NA 1.9 NA ...
  ..$ sub2: num [1:66] NA NA 1.39 NA NA 0.506 NA NA 1.06 NA ...
  ..$ tech: int [1:66] 504 504 504 504 504 504 504 504 504 504 ...

> dput(sapply(l, head, 1))
structure(list("12/31/95", NA_real_, NA_real_, 503L, "7/4/98", 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, 504L), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Date", "sub1", "sub2", "tech"), NULL))
```

Comment: Can you add output of `str(l)` and `dput(sapply(l, head, 1)` to the question?

Comment: Thanks. I just did...

Answer (score 0):

There is no "right" or "left" justification of names in `R`.  If you don't want the headers, then use the argument `headers=FALSE` in your `read.csv` calls.

Your other problems also appear at first blush to be due to lack of familiarity with `read.csv`.  I recommend reading a single file with `read.csv(file_name, header=FALSE)` and experimenting with other arguments such as `fill` until you are confident you're reading in the desired contents of your files.